# How to use Paypal "Buy button" concept in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, paypal, paypal-express, marketplace, multi-vendor

Actually i am looking for a solution on marketplace multi-vendor concept. As in Magento paypal express checkout is default which makes once buyer paid the payment will redirect to the admin paypal account directly.

But my question is how to make multiple account checkout. Actually in our marketplace sellers should add their verified paypal account in payment method place and get it verified like same in ebay and after that once email id got linked if any buyer like to buy a product from him he can buy but the payment should directly goes to the seller paypal account not the admin paypal. And this concept we have tried with parallel checkout and adaptive payment type in paypal but now a days that services not more exist in paypal. So is it possible to do through paypal buy button concept with grant application and is it possible to do a single checkout with multiple sellers products? if "Yes" could someone please explain and help me out.

I have attached some screenshot for better understanding. If still its not clear please tell me i will explain more in detail.

[image: Paypal Access]

Thanks in advance.